# JavaScript asynchronous return value / assignment with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have the following jQuery Function.  I'm trying to return the GUID value shown here in the `alert();` The alert works fine and the value is populated, however I can't seem to assign it to a variable and return its value.

Ultimately I need to access the GUID value in other functions, etc. Everything I've tried only displays as `undefined`.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
function trackPage(){
    var elqTracker = new jQuery.elq(459);
    elqTracker.pageTrack({
        success: function() {
            elqTracker.getGUID(function(guid) {
                alert(guid);
                var returnValue = guid;
            });
        }
    });
    return returnValue;
}

var someGuid = trackPage();
```

Comment: is `getGUID` an asynchronous call?

Comment: not sure.. It's a plugin call from other JS (not a call I can modify).. I can alert the value.. and even assign it to a new variable.. I just can seem to get that value outside of the function

Comment: Definitely sounds asynchronous, in that case.

Comment: its not just the sp mistake is it - returnValuRRRRe?

Comment: sorry.. that was just a typo.. corrected.. (unrelated)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

So, this question has been asked a million times over, and I'm sure that everyone (myself included) [tried this once](http://fixingthesejquery.com/#slide42).

It is just the nature of an asynchronous call, you can't use their results as a `return` value.  Thats why they have you passing in a function that gets the result of the call, they can't `return` it either!  Also notice that the `elqTracker.pageTrack()` function call returns IMMEDIATELY, therefore your `returnValue` is simply `undefined`.

Most people (see dfsq's answer) solve this problem by introducing a callback function as a paramater. This method is tried, and true – however jQuery has [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).  This allows you to make your own asynchronous logic return a `promise` which you can then attach any number of callbacks to:

```
function trackPage(){
    var elqTracker = new jQuery.elq( 459 ),
        dfd = $.Deferred();

    elqTracker.pageTrack({
        success: function() {
            elqTracker.getGUID(function( guid ) {
                dfd.resolve( guid );
            });
        }
    });

    return dfd.promise();
}

// example use:
trackPage().done(function( guid ) {
    alert( "Got GUID:" + guid );
});
```

Notice now that your `trackPage()` returns an object that you can attach callbacks to?  You don't have to attach them immediately either.

```
var pageHit = trackPage().done(function( guid ) {
    alert( "Page Hit GUID:" +guid );
});

$("button").click(function() {
    pageHit.done( function( guid ) {
        alert( "Clicked on Page GUID:" + guid );
    });
});
```

Also, the jQuery AJAX module always returns promises as well, so the interface for all your AJAX stuff should be very similar if you make your own logic return promises.

---

As a side note: I'd like to point out that your `var returnValue` was in the wrong "scope" anyway.  It needed to be declared in the outer scope of the `trackPage` function.  Even with this fix, the concept still doesn't work.

Answer (score 14):

Since you have asynchronous call the way you are trying to write code is not going to work (because by the moment of `return returnValue;` in the trackCode return value is not yet defined). Instead you should pass callback into trackPage:

```
function trackPage(callback) {
    var elqTracker = new jQuery.elq(459);
    elqTracker.pageTrack({
        success: function() {
            elqTracker.getGUID(function(guid) {
                alert(guid);
                // Instead of this: var returnValue = guid;
                // You should use your callback function
                callback(guid);
            });
        }
    });
    return returnValue;
}

trackCode(function(guid) {
    // perform some actions with guid
});
```