# Trying to use JSON value outside $.getJSON function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript asynchronous return value / assignment with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779697/javascript-asynchronous-return-value-assignment-with-jquery)

I have the following javascript code, the time.php file has minute and hour output using json_encode function.  If I move console.log inside the getJSON function it finds the correct values, however when I move it outside the function it shows as undefined.

```
var my_hour;

$.getJSON('../scripts/time.php', function(data) {
    my_hour = data.hour;
});

console.log(my_hour);
```

Comment: The proposed duplicate is not generic enough to be considered as a duplicate to this question.

Answer (score 1):

it's because it's asynchronous. Ajax request made by `$.getJson` async call your script and variables my_hour is initialized after your `console.log(my_hour).`

If you want it to work that way, then you should put `console.log` in some setInterval.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
   if (my_hour != undefined){
     console.log(my_hour);
     clearInterval(interval);
   }
}, 200);
```

But it's it's not a good practice anyway.., your code should be placed in callback function as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

The "$.getJSON" call is asynchronous; the interaction with the server takes time but the browser does not wait for it to finish.  Thus, your code *after* the function call runs immediately, a long time before the callback runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_hour;

$.getJSON('../scripts/time.php', function(data) {
    my_hour = data.hour;
    console.log(my_hour);
});
```