# Defering return statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript asynchronous return value / assignment with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779697/javascript-asynchronous-return-value-assignment-with-jquery)

I need a prototype of chart with constructor, so I wrote this:

```
function Chart(file) {
  var chart = undefined

  $.getJSON(file, function(data) {

    chart = {
      categories: data.keys
      series: [{
          name: 'first',
          data: data.first
        }, {
          name: 'second',
          data: data.second
      }]
    }

  });

  return chart
}
```

Then I realized, that because of JaavScript's synchronousness it returns `undefined`. How should I defere the return statement of `Chart`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1.) Specify a callback function

```
function Chart(file, callback) {
  var chart = undefined

  $.getJSON(file, function(data) {

    chart = {
      categories: data.keys
      series: [{
          name: 'first',
          data: data.first
        }, {
          name: 'niewykopane',
          data: data.first
      }]
    }
    callback(chart);

  });
}
```

#### 2.) Synchronous request (not recommended!)

You could use `$.ajax()` and set the `async` property to `false`.

**Warning:** This method is *not recommended*! It blocks the whole UI, all other JavaScript and timers until the request is finished!

Comment: If you're going to suggest `async:false`, please outline, stress and **bold** the disadvantages of doing so.

Comment: I hoped that there is a nicer solution than callback, because I'm initializing object like that: `hour_occurrences = new Highcharts.Chart(new Chart(file))`. But thanks, it works:).