# return function value from $.post callback

Tags: jquery

**js:**

```
 function verificaExistPed(numped){
        var valida;
        jQuery.post("procedures/class_oc.php", // ajax post
            {
                cache      : false,
                checkYear  : true,
                numped     : numped
            },
            function(data)
            {
                if(data === "s"){
                    valida = true;
                }else{
                    valida = false;
                }
            }
        )
        return valida;
  }
```

and, calling the function in another place, should return `valida` result inside variable `check`, in my case, `true` or `false`.

```
var check = verificaExistPed('".$numped."');
alert(check); // always undifined
```

but, always undefined.

how can i set `valida` to `true` or `false` from a `$.post` callback ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript asynchronous return value / assignment with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779697/javascript-asynchronous-return-value-assignment-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return from as `jQuery.post` is an asynchronous call. You have to rely on a callback function in order to get the response from server. Try this:

```
 function verificaExistPed(numped, isValidCallback){
        jQuery.post("procedures/class_oc.php", // ajax post
            {
                cache      : false,
                checkYear  : true,
                numped     : numped
            },
            function(data)
            {
                isValidCallback(data === "s");
            }
        )
  }
```

**USAGE:**

```
verificaExistPed('".$numped."', function(isValid) {
   alert(isValid); //returns true or false
});
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, I should have done some modifications to RicardoArruda code

Comment: @T.J.Crowder surely I could :) better be late than never :)

Answer (score 2):

It's because handler are invoked asinchronously after your functon invoked. So you synchronously request for it, like:

```
function test() {
    var html = $.ajax({
    url: "procedures/class_oc.php",
       async: false // <-- heres the key !
    }).responseText;

    return html;
}
```

Comment: Making synchronous calls is a bad idea in general, as it can freeze the browser.

Comment: Yep, but in this case if OP need a result of the function with ajax request it's only way to do it.

Comment: No it's not the only way. He should pass a callback instead and put all the logic that needs this result into the callback. It's pretty straightforward with jQuery's deferred objects (see the duplicate question I linked to).

Comment: This will freeze the browser (atleast IE)

Comment: If you passing the callback it's already not a result of invoking, it will invoke your callback after ajax call and it can be not a case in OP situation if he needs this value just after calling.

Comment: That's how you are going to design to work along async calls. Hampering UX is the worst thing ever.