# How can I get the return value of jquery post function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

```
function readMemory(ptr, size)
{
    $.post("readMemory.php", { ptr : ptr, size : size}, function(data)
    {

    });     

    //return "data"
}
```

Hi, I just want to get data variable as return of readMemory function. Is there any proper way to do this?

Comment: Since it is an asynchronous call, the `data` is not available yet when the function returns.  You can assign the `data` to some variable in the `success` function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [return function value from $.post callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414371/return-function-value-from-post-callback)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript asynchronous return value / assignment with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779697/javascript-asynchronous-return-value-assignment-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do is use a callback:

```
function readMemory(ptr, size, callback)
{
    $.post("readMemory.php", { ptr : ptr, size : size}, function(data)
    {
        callback(data, ptr, size);
    });     
}
```

(Note that we have `ptr` and `size` being passed to `callback` as well as `data`; this is usually good practice.)

So code you were expecting to use `readMemory` like this:

```
var data = readMemory(ptr, 100);
doSomethingWith(data);
doSomethingElseWith(data);
```

...will instead look like this:

```
readMemory(ptr, 100, function(data) {
    doSomethingWith(data);
    doSomethingElseWith(data);
});
```

This is because your `readMemory` function only *starts* the `POST` operation; it returns before the operation completes (the operation is *asynchronous*).

Answer (score 3):

The *improper* way would be to make it a synchronous request (which I think would require using the lower level [`ajax` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of `post`).

The proper way would be to forget about returning anything and use your callback function to do whatever you need to do with the data.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is asynchronous. This means that by the time your `readMemory` function returns, the result might not be available yet.

The only place that you can reliably consume the results of an AJAX call is inside the success callback:

```
function readMemory(ptr, size)
{
    $.post("readMemory.php", { ptr : ptr, size : size}, function(data)
    {
        // here and only here you can use data
    });     

    // at this stage there is no way to get the data 
}
```

So the proper way is to not return anything from your function and do whatever you intended to do with those results **inside** the callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tabela;

function doSomethingWith(response) 
{    
 tabela = response;
}

function get_more(id)
{        
    var a =  id + 11;
    var b =  id + 21;

    $.post("../php/empresas/empresas_tab.php",{id:a, _id:b},function(data){
         doSomethingWith(data);
        $("#tabEMP").html(data);
        //console.error(data);
    });
}
```