# Best way to retrieve Firebase data and return it, or an alternative way

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase for some projects and am liking the platform a lot.

I just stumbled upon a thing that I could not do and was wondering if there was any way to achieve it or if there was an alternative way of doing it.

What I am trying to do is to create a function to retrieve the last X number of entries from my Firebase database and returning the data to the calling function.

Something like this:

```
function getTwoLatestLocations()
{
    var twoLocations;
    myFirebaseRef.limitToLast(2).once('value', function (dataSnapshot) {
        twoLocations = dataSnapshot.val();
    }, function (errorObject) {
        // code to handle read error
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });

    return twoLocations;
}
```

And then calling it like this:

```
function someCalcutationsWithTheTwoLastLocations()
{
    var twoLastLocations = getTwoLatestLocations();
    // Do some calculations
}
```

But as you might have guessed the call to the database reference is asynchronous  so the returning object will always be undefined.

Is there a way to do this elegantly so I can keep the methods separated?

P.S. Currently all my code is simply inside the call to the database. Ugly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To separate the code out, you'd pass in a callback:

```
function getTwoLatestLocations(callback)
{
    var twoLocations;
    myFirebaseRef.limitToLast(2).once('value', function (dataSnapshot) {
        twoLocations = dataSnapshot.val();
        callback(twoLocations);
    }, function (errorObject) {
        // code to handle read error
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });

}
```

And then calling it like this:

```
function someCalcutationsWithTheTwoLastLocations()
{
    getTwoLatestLocations(function(twoLocations) {
        // Do some calculations
    });
}
```

The important thing to always remember is that you cannot wait for something that is loaded asynchronously.

This has been covered quite a few times, including in this top answer from the list of related questions: [Handling Asynchronous Calls (Firebase) in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636731/handling-asynchronous-calls-firebase-in-functions?rq=1)

Comment: Yes. That is one of two options. 
I chose to go with the other option. To cache my snapshot every time the on method is called.
I guess it is just a matter of preference. I will mark this as the correct answer since you mention one possibility and provide a link that includes the other.
Would have answered this myself if nobody would have answered by now. Thanks.

Comment: If my answer was useful, upvote it. If my answer provided you the solution you went with, accept it. I you picked another solution, self-answer and accept that one. That is completely acceptable here on StackOverflow.