# Not getting data from firebase on opening the app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to get data from firebase but it returns empty value when the app loads, but if I edit something on that file even the commented line, then the data loads and app runs, I want when the app opens all data should be there from firebase to run app. and also how to arrange "grabbedData" in reverse order tried grabbedData.reverse() but doent work.

```
  const Getdata = async () => {
    let grabbedData = [];

    await firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`/users/`)
      .orderByKey()
      .on("value", (snapshot, key) => {
        // console.log("snapshot....", snapshot);
        grabbedData.push(snapshot.val());
      });
    setUserdata(grabbedData);
    console.log("grabbedData", grabbedData); // empty value here :(
    if (grabbedData) {
      let getfranchiseuid = "";
      Object.keys(grabbedData).map(function (key) {
        let y = grabbedData[key];
        Object.keys(y).map(function (key2) {
          let x = y[key2];
          if (key2 === uid) {
            getfranchiseuid = x.franchiseuid;
          }
        });
      });

      if (getfranchiseuid) {
        let customerList1 = [];
        firebase
          .database()
          .ref(`/serviceProvider/${getfranchiseuid}/franchise/customers`)
          .orderByKey()
          .on("value", (snapshot) => {
            customerList1.push(snapshot.val());
          });
        setCustomerList(customerList1);
        console.log("customerList1customerList1", customerList1);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      if (user) {
        storeUser({ user });
        setUser(user);
        setEmail(user.email);
        setUid(user.uid);
      } else {
        // No user is signed in.
      }
    });
    unsubscribe();
    Getdata();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously. Since this may take some time, your main JavaScript code will continue to run, so that the user can continue to use the app while the data is loading. Then when the data is available, your callback is invoked with that data.

What this means in your code is that (for example) right now your `setUserdata` is called before the `grabbedData.push(snapshot.val())` has run, so you're setting any empty user data. You can most easily see this by setting some breakpoints on the code and running it in a debugger, or by adding logging and checking the order of its output.

```
console.log("1");
await firebase
  .database()
  .ref(`/users/`)
  .orderByKey()
  .on("value", (snapshot, key) => {
    console.log("2");
  });
console.log("3");
```

When you run this code, the output will be:

> 1
>
> 3
>
> 2

This is probably not what you expected, but it is exactly correct and does explain your problems.

---

The solution for this is always the same: **any code that needs the data from the database must be *inside* the callback, or be called from there.**

So for example:

```
await firebase
  .database()
  .ref(`/users/`)
  .orderByKey()
  .on("value", (snapshot, key) => {
    grabbedData.push(snapshot.val());
    setUserdata(grabbedData);
  });
```

this will ensure that `setUserdata` is called whenever you updated the `grabbedData`.

---

Since you have much more code that depends on `grabbedData`, that will also have to be inside the callback. So the entire `if (grabbedData) {` block will need to be moved, and probably others. If you keep applying the solution above, the code will start working.

This is a very common problem for developers that are new to calling asynchronous cloud APIs, so I highly recommend reading some of these other answers:

- [Why Does Firebase Lose Reference outside the once() Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688268/why-does-firebase-lose-reference-outside-the-once-function/40688890#40688890)
- [Best way to retrieve Firebase data and return it, or an alternative way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905600/best-way-to-retrieve-firebase-data-and-return-it-or-an-alternative-way/34908497#34908497)
- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) (this one is not specific to Firebase, as the problem is not specific to Firebase)