# How to retrieve the content of a variable that is in a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I created this function:

```
var IDOfUserToKill = 'tralala';

export function getIDOfUserToKill(userID, gameID) {
  let path = '/games/' + gameID + '/users/' + userID;

  fb.database().ref(path).on('value', snapshot => {
      IDOfUserToKill = '';

      if (snapshot.val()) {
        IDOfUserToKill = snapshot.val().userToKill;
        console.log(IDOfUserToKill); // return the good ID
      }
    });
}

userID = IDOfUserToKill; // return "tralala" and not the good ID
```

Then I want to use the variable `IDOfUserToKill` outside this one. Because if I use `IDOfUserToKill`, it returns the value that was defined before the function (tralala) and not the ID.

How to retrieve the content of the variable? (I use React Native).

Comment: Is ```fb.database().ref(path).on('value', snapshot => {}``` asynchronous ? Because that would explain why you don't log the correct value. You are probably assigning `IDOfUserToKill` to `userID` before the function finished executing.

Comment: Why do you expect that an export of a function (note that you do not call it) will change the value of `IDOfUserToKill`?

Comment: No, I just exported the function because I'm using it in a different file.

Comment: So how do I recover the content? Do you have any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function:

```
 fb.database().ref(path).on('value', snapshot => {
  IDOfUserToKill = '';

  if (snapshot.val()) {
    IDOfUserToKill = snapshot.val().userToKill;
    console.log(IDOfUserToKill); // return the good ID
  }
});
```

is asynchronous which means it moves on to another task before it finishes.

That is why inside `on()` you get the `id` that is in the database, while outside, here `userID = IDOfUserToKill;` you get the value `'tralala'`.

To learn more about asychronous check this:

https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93

Comment: I this case it doesn't even matter if it is asynchronous or not. OP defines a variable `IDOfUserToKill` then exports a function (without calling it) and the assigns the value of `IDOfUserToKill` to another variable which of course has the current value of `IDOfUserToKill` which is `'tralala'`.

Comment: @Jean did the answer help you?

Comment: Okay, I understand the principle. So how do I recover the content? Do you have any examples?

Comment: @Jean here check this, same problem that you have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636731/handling-asynchronous-calls-firebase-in-functions Tell me if you did not understand it. Also upvote and mark as correct this answer so people know it is helpful

Comment: I don't really understand, can you give me an example with my function?

Comment: @Jean  you can just add this `userID = IDOfUserToKill` instead `on()` and when u want to use `userID` just use it inside the function so you get the right value

Comment: @Jean check this: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises

Comment: Okay, but isn't there a way to get the content out of the function?