# returning a variable form an async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a module with a function which generates the value for a vaariable for a variable "stitcheBook". I can see and use this value using a callback.

However, I want to have this value available to me as a module property. How can i achieve this?

Note: I wish the output of the _BookStitcher.stitchAllStories function to go into the _BookStitcher.stitchedBook property.

```
module.exports = _BookStitcher = (function() {

var db = require('../modules/db');
var stitchedBook = {};

var stitchAllStories = function(callback) {


    db.dbConnection.smembers("storyIdSet", function (err, reply) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
            var storyList = reply;
            console.log(storyList);
            // start a separate multi command queue
            multi = db.dbConnection.multi();
            for (var i=0; i<storyList.length; i++) {
                multi.hgetall('story/' + String(storyList[i]) + '/properties');
            };
            // drains multi queue and runs atomically
            multi.exec(function (err, replies) {
                stitchedBook = replies;
                // console.log(stitchedBook);
                callback(stitchedBook);
            });
        };
    });


};


return {
    stitchedBook : stitchedBook,
    stitchAllStories: stitchAllStories

}
```

})();

EDIT: to add: I know that I can actually set the value from outside by doing something like this;

```
_BookStitcher.stitchAllStories(function (reply) {
        console.log("Book has been stitched!\n\n")
        console.log("the Book is;\n");
        console.log(reply);
        _BookStitcher.stitchedBook = reply;
        console.log("-------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n\n");
        console.log(_BookStitcher.stitchedBook);

});
```

I was wondering if there was a way of doing it from inside the _BookStitcher module itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript asynchronous return value / assignment with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779697/javascript-asynchronous-return-value-assignment-with-jquery)

Comment: Aren't you already doing that in `stitchedBook = replies;`? The problem is, you can't know when the value will be available, it's only safe to use it from the callback, when you're sure it's been set.

Comment: sorry. please see my edit. I can get the value. I was just wondering if i can set the value from inside the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* take advantage of how object references work in JavaScript, and assign it to a property:

```
module.exports = _BookStitcher = (function() {

    var db = require('../modules/db');

    // CHANGE HERE
    var stitched = { book: null };

    var stitchAllStories = function(callback) {
        db.dbConnection.smembers("storyIdSet", function (err, reply) {
            if (err) throw err;
            else {
                var storyList = reply;
                console.log(storyList);
                // start a separate multi command queue
                multi = db.dbConnection.multi();
                for (var i=0; i<storyList.length; i++) {
                    multi.hgetall('story/' + String(storyList[i]) + '/properties');
                };
                // drains multi queue and runs atomically
                multi.exec(function (err, replies) {
                    // CHANGE HERE
                    stitched.book = replies;
                    // console.log(stitchedBook);
                    callback(replies);
                });
            };
        });
    };

    return {
        stitched : stitched,
        stitchAllStories: stitchAllStories
    };

}());
```

So instead of having it inside `_BookStitcher.stitchedBook`, you'd have it at `_BookStitcher.stitched.book`.

But that looks awful, and I'd never use it! **You can't know when the value will be available, it's only safe to use it from the callback, when you're sure it's been set.**

Comment: Thanks. I probably wouldn't use it but I just had to know. -_-