# How to switch on geolocation in Google Maps Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-geolocation

I use library [Angular Google Maps](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/)
In documentation I have not found nothing about geolocation. I need use an optional plug-in for it? How to use geolocation in this library?

Comment: It doesn't look like that library has location services. You'll probably need a different library or maybe try using [html5 geolocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185619/how-can-i-use-html5-geolocation-in-angularjs).

Answer (score 0):

I have used [AngularJS-Geolocation](https://github.com/arunisrael/angularjs-geolocation). It is easy to use this library to obtenir the geolocation without security limits like HTTPS requirements. (If you are trying to use `window.navigator.geolocation`, it will require HTTPS for safty reason.)

This module is available as bower package, install it with this command:

```
bower install angularjs-geolocation
```

The usage like this

```
angular.module('barterApp',['geolocation'])
  .controller('geoCtrl', function ($scope,geolocation) {
    geolocation.getLocation().then(function(data){
      $scope.coords = {lat:data.coords.latitude, long:data.coords.longitude};
    });
});
```

Here is a [live demo](http://embed.plnkr.co/TM71LBh6ttYotOo6t7oX/). Hope this could be helpful.