# Can't display $scope variable in view angular

Tags: angularjs

Here's my controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')

.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$geolocation', function($scope, $geolocation) {
    $geolocation.getCurrentPosition({
      timeout: 6000
    }).then(function(position) {
      $scope.position = position;
      $scope.myText = 'Text to show';
      console.log(position);
      console.log($scope.position);
    })
  } 
])
```

And in template:

```
   {{ position }} <br/>
   {{ myText }}
```

Now, in my console, I get this object

```
Geoposition {coords: Coordinates, timestamp: 1476965809589}
```

A sign the position came in

In template, I get this:

```
{} 
Text to show
```

So, why ain't the `$scope.position` not showing in my template, although the `Text to show` shows, and the console log confirms the `$scope.position` is available?

My `home.html`:

```
    <div class="small-12 columns">
        <div class="callout clearfix" style="margin-top:20px;">
            <h5 class="float-center">Welcome Home.</h5>
            {{ position }} <br/>
            {{ myText }}
            <div ng-show="!position" class="float-center">
                <div class="loader">
                    <span>{</span><span>}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and state:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
  })
```

Comment: In the template you are already using `HomeController` like: `<div ng-controller="HomeController">{{position}}</div>`?

Comment: can you add the full html pls??

Comment: can you try this:  .controller('HomeController', ['$scope', '$geolocation', function($scope, $geolocation) {
   
    $scope.model = {};

    $geolocation.getCurrentPosition({
      timeout: 6000
    }).then(function(position) {
      $scope.model.position = position;
      $scope.myText = 'Text to show';
      console.log(position);
      console.log($scope.model.position);
    })
  } 
])

In the template:  {{model.position}}</br>  {{myText}}  Angular needs dotted notation for some objects to be resolved.

Comment: Try initializing position by `$scope.position = {};` before the `$geolocation.getCurrentPosition({` .

Comment: Also check [THIS SO LINK ON GEOLOCATION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185619/how-can-i-use-html5-geolocation-in-angularjs).  You may need the $scope.$apply to trigger the digest cycle.  If that doesn't give you "too many watch" ... error, you should see the geolocation stuff.

Comment: @dinony I've already assigned the Controller to the view in the $state

Comment: @Mahesh Still not working, even with your example

Comment: try to use {{position.timestamp}} inside the view and check what you get... maybe angular cant parse the geoposition object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

Had to to this, as in be specific with what I want from the `position` object

```
    <div class="callout clearfix" style="margin-top:20px;">
            <h5 class="float-center">Welcome Home.</h5>
            {{ position.timestamp }} <br/>
            {{ position.coords.latitude }} <br/> // this works 
            {{ myText }}
            <div ng-show="!position" class="float-center">
                <div class="loader">
                    <span>{</span><span>}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```