# Returning value from Javascript function when value comes from within a promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, return, promise

I am trying to return a value from an asynchronous function call, and I understand, from posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779697/javascript-asynchronous-return-value-assignment-with-jquery) that you can't use a return. However, it is implied that I should be able to accomplish this with proper use of callbacks and promises. Unfortunately, I am having a difficult time to figuring out exactly how to handle the problem I have below.

Here, I want to return a URL value that I'm obtaining from an AJAX call.

```
 function getGithubURL(name){
  var ghUserURL = 'https://api.github.com/users/bullcitydave?client_id=-----&client_secret=------';

  var jsPromise = Promise.resolve($.getJSON(ghUserURL));

  var avatar;

  jsPromise.then(function(data) {
      avatar = data.avatar_url;
      console.log(avatar);  // I have the correct value here
    });

  return avatar; // how do I return it correctly?
};
```

Comment: you can't do that... the only solution is to use a callback method to handle the value returned from the promise

Comment: You can "return" it by passing a callback function to your `getGithubURL` function, calling that inside the `jsPromise.then` (and passing it the `data.avatar_url`, and inside that callback running `console.log('The URL for my Github image is',x);`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sXu3r/1/

Comment: @benjamin-gruenbaum - do you really want to mark this as a dup of that question?  The crux of this question is really how to use promises to get a piece of an ajax result out of his function.  The question you marked this a dup of deals with the async problem he has, but offers zero help with how to use promises to solve the issue (see my answer where I attempted to address that).  I decided to vote to reopen.  The question you marked it a dup of only addresses one part of this question and not the more interesting part in my opinion.

Comment: I think the first paragraph strongly implies that OP's big issue here is how to return from an asynchronous function and that using promises is just an approach OP has tried - " with proper use of callbacks and promises.". Having a promises answer on _that_ question and explaining how to use them to handle returns of async values might be useful on the other hand.

Comment: Thanks Arun and I for the examples. However, I need to go back and clarify my question. I am needing to return this avatar URL value to a process I don't have control over. The first line and last night were meant to make for a simple example.

Comment: I should clarify my question. I am needing to return this avatar URL value to a process I don't have control over. The var x and console.log lines are besides the point. I was trying to indicate that I need to call a single function that returns the value I need. I don't care if that single function has several chained functions within it. 

As far as this question being marked a dup of another, I wish you would not do that. I am posting this specific question because "similar" questions haven't helped me, and I need a specific answer.  @jfriend00 thanks you for voting to reopen.

Comment: @bullcitydave - You can't just return the value synchronously.  You will have to return it via a callback function or a promise (which is really just a callback too, but in a helpful structure).  I agree with Benjamin that if you're still trying to return an async value from a synchronous function, then you should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call because that is NOT something that javascript can do.  An alternative would be to force the async ajax call to be synchronous, but that is generally a bad design decision.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call ? You should really consider reading it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a value in your synchronous function that was acquired from an asynchronous operation.  The async operation won't complete until sometime later so it simply isn't available yet when your `getGithubURL()` function returns.  It's a matter of timing and just something that javascript can't do.

You can solve your problem by restructuring how you use promises.  What you want to do is to make a `.then()` handler be the consumer of the final data.  That way you can pass the data back through your promise structure.  You also want to make use of the promise that `$.getJSON()` already returns - no need to create your own promise here.

Here's one way to do that.

```
getGithubURL("bullcitydave").then(function(url) {
    // you can use the avatar url here
});

function getGithubURL(name){
  var ghUserURL = 'https://api.github.com/users/bullcitydave?client_id=-----&client_secret=------';

  return $.getJSON(ghUserURL).then(function(data) {
      return data.avatar_url;
  });
};
```

You call `$.getJSON()`.  It returns a promise which you add a `.then()` handler on in order to extract the actual data you want.  From the `.then()` handler, you return the final data you want.  The `$.getJSON().then()` sequence creates a new promise which is what you return from your `getGithubURL()` function and is not resolved until the `getJSON().then()` sequence is done.  That will present your avatar URL to the outer `.then()` handler as shown in the code
above.

---

Or, if the caller of your `getGithubURL()` function isn't going to use promises, then you can make your function take a callback like this:

```
getGithubURL("bullcitydave", function(url) {
    // you can use the avatar url here
});

function getGithubURL(name, fn) {
  var ghUserURL = 'https://api.github.com/users/bullcitydave?client_id=-----&client_secret=------';

  $.getJSON(ghUserURL).then(function(data) {
      // call the callback and pass it the avatar url
      fn(data.avatar_url);
  });
};
```

Comment: @bullcitydave - Added a plain callback option for `getGithubURL()`.

Comment: thank you for your time and the responses are giving me valuable understanding. This is a difficult problem for me to explain. It seems like no matter what route I go, I am left with a return value corresponding to a secondary function all.  What I really have a primary function wrapping all of this up, and the primary function needs to report the result. 

So, if looking at your last code snippet, imagine a basic higher-up function within which nests all of your code How can I have that code return data.avatar_url? Does what I am asking make sense?  I truly appeciate this feedback and...

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00, I don't doubt you and I am grateful for the feedback. Best regards!