# JavaScript/JQuery: Best way to avoid nesting of asynchronous functions / anonymous callback functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

My JavaScript code contains quite a few asynchronous functions. For example, I'm using D3.JS to read a CSV file, and I'm connecting to the Google Maps API to find the driving directions between two addresses.

I'm using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779697/javascript-asynchronous-return-value-assignment-with-jquery) on StackOverflow to wait until the asynchronous function is complete (to avoid return variables with a `undefined` value). However, because I have a lot of asynchronous functions, I have a lot of nested anonymous callback functions:

```
    carDirections(from, to).done(function(car) {
        transitDirections(from, to).done(function(train) {
        // carDirections and trainDirections have similar anonymous callback functions.

    function carDirections(from, to) {
        var dfd = $.Deferred();

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

        directionsService.route({
            origin: from,
            destination: to,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function(response, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                dfd.resolve(response.routes[0].legs[0]);
            }
        });

        return dfd.promise();
    }
    // Similar code for transitDirections.
```

This results in a spaghetti of `done` and `Deferred` functions, which makes the code very hard to understand. Is there a proper way to solve this? E.g., could I re-program my Google Maps functions to make them synchrounous, or is there another (easier) way to only continue executing code when the previous function has returned a variable?

Comment: Have u looked into promises?

Comment: @blessenm Yes, that's what I'm trying in the post above. This results in a large nesting of promises and I was wondering if this could be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to [read up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) some more on the subject of `Promise`s. You can chain asynchronous operations like

```
asyncOp1()
  .then(result1 => asyncOp2(result1))
  .then(result2 => asyncOp3(result2))
  .then(result3 => Promise.all(asyncOp4(result3), asyncOp5(result3)))
  .catch(error => { /* deal with an error */ })
  // ...
```

if all of the operations return a `Promise` (this helps you avoid nesting). ([Transpile](http://babeljs.io/repl/) the above pseudo-code to ES5 and [polyfill](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise) the `Promise` if you need to.)

---

If you're looking for different ways to deal with complex asynchronous code alltogether, you check out [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) ... not that I'm taking any responsibility if you do :)

Comment: That seems like a nice solution, thanks! However, if I have the following code: `carDirections(from, to).then(car => trainDirections(from, to)).then(train => console.log(car));`, the variable `car` isn't accessible anymore. Is there a way to keep passing this variable on, other than sending it along as a function argument?

Comment: You could save to an outer scope variable or extend the `Promise` monad to collect all of the results in the chain, but it's easiest and most transparent to just send whatever you need along. If you don't want to pollute your train op function, you can always do`carOp().then(car => trainOp(car).then(train => ({ car, train }))).then(({ car, train }) => ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see the trainDirections does't need to get any response from carDirections you just need to fire a callback when all of the actions are finished?

You could use deferred objects.

```
var deferredObj1 = $.Deferred(),
    deferredObj2 = $.Deferred();

$.when(deferredObj1,deferredObj2).done(function(){
    console.log("They are both done!");
});

// inside the Event1 handler:
deferredObj1.resolve();

// inside the Event2 handler:
deferredObj2.resolve();
```

> The Deferred object, introduced in jQuery 1.5, is a chainable utility
>   object created by calling the jQuery.Deferred() method. It can
>   register multiple callbacks into callback queues, invoke callback
>   queues, and relay the success or failure state of any synchronous or
>   asynchronous function.