# Pass ajax response as argument to custom function

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I'm developing a custom jQuery tooltip function with some parameters, such as 'content', which can be predefined. Now I want to add the possibility to fetch some html / json with an ajax callback and pass this to the 'content'-parameter, but I can't get it to work.

My function looks like this:

```
$("div.tooltip").each(function(){
    $(this).myTooltip({
        'content':$.ajax({
                url: '/request.php',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    action:'getcontent',
                    date:$(this).attr('rel')
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(result) {
                    return result;
                }
              }),
        'someotherargs': .....

    });
});
```

The content within the tooltip will be '[object XMLHttpRequest]' so I assume the callback object is returned, not the response..

What am I doing wrong (besides that there may be some typo in the ajax callback)?
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [return from a function ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381804/return-from-a-function-ajax)

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Maybe there is a different way to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to fetch the tooltip content with an ajax callback and passing the ajax response to my custom jquery function through the 'content' parameter. Then my custom function inserts the content received through this parameter into a div (the tooltip). The content received by the ajax callback will eventually be some json, which will be rendered by the custom function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.tooltip").each(function(){
    var myThis = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/request.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            action:'getcontent',
            date:$(myThis).attr('rel')
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result) {
            $(myThis).myTooltip({
                'content': result,
                'someotherargs': .....
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm getting the XMLHttpRequest returned as object, that's one step ahead of getting the json returned I assume.